# Using non-fractional complex number in Haskell

Tags: haskell

When using the native *Data.Complex* implementation in Haskell, constructing a complex number using non-fractional type using Int is possible. However, it is impossible to perform any calculation with it:

```
> let x = 1:+1 :: Complex Int
> x * x

<interactive>:44:1: error:
    * No instance for (RealFloat Int) arising from a use of `*'
    * In the expression: x * x
      In an equation for `it': it = x * x
```

This becomes a problem when I am trying to use arbitrary significance structures like *Data.Scientific* since it has no instance for RealFloat as well. What can I do to remedy this situation? Writing an instance of RealFloat for Scientifc will result in an orphan instance. Should I write my own Complex class?

Comment: To perform the operations the `Num` typeclass provides, the item type should be a member of the `RealFloat` typeclass: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Complex.html#t:Complex

Comment: This is the case because for the `signum` of a complex number, it works with `x/r + y/r i` with `r` the magnitude, and this needs the item to be an instance of the `RealFloat` typeclass.

Comment: I understand this. I was asking that with this knowledge, what solution is feasible.

Comment: you can work with `toRealFloat` to convert a `Complex Scientific` to `RealFloat a => Complex a`.

Comment: I don't understand.  `Scientific` _does_ have a `RealFloat` instance.  And if you want `Int`, maybe use `Rational` instead?

Comment: @DDub: It looks that `Scientific` is *not* an instance of `RealFloat`, it is an instance of `Real` and `RealFrac`, but not `RealFloat`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific-0.3.7.0/docs/Data-Scientific.html#t:Scientific .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to perform functions defined in the `Num` typeclass, the item `a` of `Complex a` should be a member of the `RealFloat` typeclass. Indeed, [the source code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/Data-Complex.html#instance%20Num%20(Complex%20a)) shows us:

> ```
> -- | @since 2.01
> instance  (RealFloat a) => Num (Complex a)  where
>     -- …
>     signum (0:+0)       =  0
>     signum z@(x:+y)     =  x/r :+ y/r  where r = magnitude z
> ```

Here the `signum` is the culprit, since this returns `x /r + y i / r` with `r` the magnitude of the complex number. It basically normalizes the complex number to coordinates on a unit circle:

[image: the sign of a complex number is the complex number divided by the magnitude of complex number.]

We determine the [magnitude of a complex number with [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/Data-Complex.html#line-115):

> ```
> magnitude :: (RealFloat a) => Complex a -> a
> magnitude (x:+y) =  scaleFloat k
>                      (sqrt (sqr (scaleFloat mk x) + sqr (scaleFloat mk y)))
>                     where k  = max (exponent x) (exponent y)
>                           mk = - k
>                           sqr z = z * z
> ```

Here the [**`exponent :: RealFloat a => a -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:exponent), this thus requires `a` to ben an instance of the `RealFloat` typeclass.

Since `Num` defines several methods, it is sufficient that one of these methods has a type constraint, to enforce these constraint on the `Num` class, and thus *all* the methods are defined in the `Num` instance.

> Writing an instance of RealFloat for Scientifc will result in an orphan instance.

You can make use of the [**`toRealFloat :: RealFloat a => Scientific -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific-0.3.7.0/docs/Data-Scientific.html#v:toRealFloat). We thus can work with:

```
Prelude Data.Scientific Data.Complex> let x = 1 :+ 1 :: Complex Scientific
Prelude Data.Scientific Data.Complex> let x' = toRealFloat <$> x
Prelude Data.Scientific Data.Complex> x' * x'
0.0 :+ 2.0
```

Comment: Does the precision gets affected by the toRealFloat conversion? If so I might just use Double instead.

Comment: @w41g87: yes, since `Scientific` has arbitrary precision whereas `toRealFloat` converts this to `Double` or `Float`.